# Melhorar performance de consulta SQL que contabiliza registro de outras tabelas

Tags: mysql

Possuo um sistema de E-learning e preciso criar um relatório para me retornar quantos alunos foram aprovados, reprovados, alunos que não acessam a mais de 30 dias, alunos que estão fazendo o curso e os que não acessaram ainda.

## As tabelas que foram utilizadas são

```
`company`            Tabela de empresas;
`company_place`      Tabela de centro de treinamentos;
`user`               Tabela de usuários;
`user_course`        Tabela que armazena a inscrição de usuários nos cursos;
`user_course_lesson` Registra as aulas assistidas pelo usuário.
```

## As regras são as seguintes

**Para alunos aprovados**: deve conter data de conclusão e o campo `approved` como 1;

**Para alunos reprovados**: deve conter data de conclusão e o campo `approved` como 0;

**Para alunos desistente**: sem data de conclusão, o campo `approved` como 0, e a última atualização na tabela `user_course_lesson` deve ser mais que 30 dias.

**Para alunos que não acessaram ainda**: Não deve existir nenhuma aula assitida na tabela `user_course_lesson`

**Para alunos com o curso em andamento**: total de registros sem data de conclusão e com o campo `approved` como 0, menos os alunos desistentes e alunos que não acessaram.

## A SQL que estou utilizando é a seguinte

```
SELECT
    /* Nome da empresa */
    c.`name`,

    /* Alunos aprovados */
    SUM( case when uc.`approved` = "1" AND uc.`finished_at` IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end ) as approved,

    /* Alunos reprovados */
    SUM( case when uc.`approved` = "0" AND uc.`finished_at` IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end ) as reproved,

    /* Alunos desistentes */
    SUM( case when uc.`approved` = "0" AND uc.`finished_at` IS NULL AND (
        SELECT 
            MAX( case when `updated_at` IS NULL then `created_at` else `updated_at` end ) as "last_access"
        FROM `user_course_lesson` as cl
        WHERE cl.`user_course_id` = uc.`id`
        ORDER BY `last_access` DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) <= DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL(-30) DAY) then 1 else 0 end ) as dropout,

    /* Alunos que não acessaram ainda */
    SUM( case when uc.`approved` = "0" AND uc.`finished_at` IS NULL AND (
        SELECT 
            COUNT( cl.`id` ) as "access"
        FROM `user_course_lesson` as cl
        WHERE cl.`user_course_id` = uc.`id`
    ) = 0 then 1 else 0 end ) as not_access,

    /* Alunos com o curso em andamento */
    SUM( case when uc.`approved` = "0" AND uc.`finished_at` IS NULL then 1 else 0 end ) - 
    SUM( case when uc.`approved` = "0" AND uc.`finished_at` IS NULL AND (
        SELECT 
            MAX( case when `updated_at` IS NULL then `created_at` else `updated_at` end ) as "last_access"
        FROM `user_course_lesson` as cl
        WHERE cl.`user_course_id` = uc.`id`
        ORDER BY `last_access` DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) <= DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL(-30) DAY) then 1 else 0 end ) -
    SUM( case when uc.`approved` = "0" AND uc.`finished_at` IS NULL AND (
        SELECT 
            COUNT( cl.`id` ) as "access"
        FROM `user_course_lesson` as cl
        WHERE cl.`user_course_id` = uc.`id`
    ) = 0 then 1 else 0 end ) as pending,
    count( uc.`id` ) as `total`
FROM `company` as c

INNER JOIN `company_place` as p
    ON p.`company_id` = c.`id`

INNER JOIN `user` as u
    ON u.`place_id` = p.`id`

INNER JOIN `user_course` as uc
    ON uc.`user_id` = u.`id`;
```

## O problema

A SQL repete muitas consultas, e o tempo para calcular com poucos registros já está alto, por volta de 0,056 segundos, com o aumento de registros esse tempo irá aumentar exponencialmente.

O ideal seria que as consultas na tabela `user_course_lesson` não se repetissem, ou tivesse uma outra forma de escrever essa SQL com JOINs ou outra forma de relacionamento.

Comment: Não me aprofundei na consulta em si, mas pela cara dela talvez seja melhor considerar pré-processar essas estatísticas de tempos em tempos, e guardá-las em algum tipo de cache (por exemplo, em outra tabela).

Comment: Já considerei isso, porem o custo de manutenção que tinha na versão antiga do mesmo projeto, era muito alto. Constantemente tinha que averiguar as contas, sem falar que o projeto tem várias empresas cadastradas, e acesso de cerca de 15000 alunos diariamente por empresa. Acreditava muito que guardar isso em outra tabela seria a solução, mas sofri demais por fazer isso. Era muito dado em uma tabela só, e pouca confiabilidade. Estava pensando em criar alguma view ou algo do tipo, mas não sei se o ganho de performance seria muito vantajoso.

Comment: Preciso melhorar o pouco que for a consulta, pois dá pra armazenar no memcache depois e não ter que executar ela toda vez. Outro detalhe é que o projeto sofre constantemente auditoria, por isso a preocupação com a confiabilidade dos dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução teve uma redução de quatro consultas, porem teve a necessidade de incluir um `LEFT JOIN`, pois preciso que a tabela me retorne os registros da tabela `user_course` mesmo que não tenha relacionamento com `user_course_lesson`.

Alterei a sintaxe `CASE` para `IF` apenas para melhorar a leitura.

Antes a consulta levava em média 0,056 segundos, agora diminuiu para 0,006 segundos.

```
SELECT
    /* Nome da empresa */
    c.`name`,

    /* Alunos aprovados */
    SUM( IF( uc.`approved` = "1" AND uc.`finished_at` IS NOT NULL, 1, 0 ) ) as approved,

    /* Alunos reprovados */
    SUM( IF( uc.`approved` = "0" AND uc.`finished_at` IS NOT NULL, 1, 0 ) ) as reproved,

    /* Alunos desistentes */
    SUM( IF( uc.`approved` = "0" AND uc.`finished_at` IS NULL AND uc.`date` <= DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL(-30) DAY), 1, 0 ) ) as dropout,

    /* Alunos que não acessaram ainda */
    SUM( IF( uc.`approved` = "0" AND uc.`finished_at` IS NULL AND uc.`date` IS NULL, 1, 0 ) ) as not_access,

    /* Alunos com o curso em andamento */
    SUM( IF( uc.`approved` = "0" AND uc.`finished_at` IS NULL, 1, 0 ) ) - 
    SUM( IF( uc.`approved` = "0" AND uc.`finished_at` IS NULL AND uc.`date` <= DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL(-30) DAY), 1, 0 ) ) -
    SUM( IF( uc.`approved` = "0" AND uc.`finished_at` IS NULL AND uc.`date` IS NULL, 1, 0 ) ) as pending,

    /* Total */
    count( uc.`id` ) as `total`
FROM `company` as c

INNER JOIN `company_place` as p
    ON p.`company_id` = c.`id`

INNER JOIN `user` as u
    ON u.`place_id` = p.`id`

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        uc.`id`,
        uc.`user_id`,
        uc.`approved`,
        uc.`finished_at`,
        MAX( IF( cl.`updated_at` IS NULL, cl.`created_at`, cl.`updated_at` ) ) as "date"
    FROM `user_course` as uc
    LEFT JOIN `user_course_lesson` as cl
    ON cl.`user_course_id` = uc.`id`
    GROUP BY uc.`id`
)  as uc
ON uc.`user_id` = u.`id`

GROUP BY c.`id`;
```